# Can I use Jacoco to check code coverage of an executable file .exe in the same way it does this with Jars?

Tags: java, integration-testing, jacoco

I am attempting to create a test execution framework to run integration tests on a java application and was wondering how I would go about generating a code coverage report based off of the applications executabe file the test runner is using to start the application and only this. Is it possible to do this like it is done with unit testing within the applications project?

I've tried adding the jacoco agent as a VM option

```
-javaagent:(filepath)jacocoagent.jar=destfile=(filepath)jacoco.exec,includes=com.*,append=true
```

in IntelliJ however the .exec its producing is 0 bytes in size after task execution is finished.